# How to access the setup tool in chocolate-doom?

Tags: command-line, games

[The documentation](https://www.chocolate-doom.org/wiki/index.php/Command_line_arguments) mentions no command-line arguments for launching [the setup program](https://www.chocolate-doom.org/wiki/index.php/Setup). The Windows version appears to have a dedicated executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a separate executable on Linux too, `chocolate-doom-setup` (which is a link to `chocolate-setup`).

Each game variant has its own setup: `chocolate-heretic-setup`, `chocolate-hexen-setup`, `chocolate-strife-setup`.

Comment: Thanks, I found more via tab-completion (which you may want to add to your answer): `chocolate-doom           chocolate-heretic-setup  chocolate-server
chocolate-doom-setup     chocolate-hexen          chocolate-strife
chocolate-heretic        chocolate-hexen-setup    chocolate-strife-setup`

Comment: They all serve different purposes, but yes, I’ll add them.